# Unable to Remote Desktop over VPN

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

Really strange. 
I am able to Remote Desktop over VPN to one of the servers (xxx.xxx.xxx.26), but not to another (xxx.xxx.xxx.27). The servers are on the same subnet.

The funny part is that if I remote desktop to the first server, then I can do second Remote Desktop from there to the other server (the one I cannot access directly - xxx.xxx.xxx.27).

So there is no credentials or login issue I guess. Just something prevents the Remote Desktop over VPN to one of the servers.

Any ideas what might be?
I wonder if the number 27 in the 4th octet of an IP has some special designation which conflicts with the VPN.

Comment: What OS versions are the servers and your computer running?  I've seen issues where some versions of remote desktop refuse to talk with others.

Answer (score 0):

What is your network configuration?  Are the two servers on the same subnet? If not is there a route setup in the VPN config to the server you are unable to RDP to?

Comment: Yes, the servers are on the same subnet. Just the last octets are different.

xxx.xxx.xxx.26  VS. xxx.xxx.xxx.27

I wonder if the 27 octet has some special designation?!

Answer (score 0):

The only people who can help you in this issue are the network support of the place with the VPN. The servers might be on separate sub-nets and they'll help you set up your routing.